# SSH, remote command taken as ssh command options

Tags: ssh, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to launch the `-V` command remotely<sup>1</sup>, thanks to a `ssh` command. I use the form: `ssh [user@]host [command]`, so I type on a command line:

```
ssh myself@remotehost -V
```

However, the `-V` argument is not taken as a command that should be executed on the remote host, but as a option given to the local `ssh` client instead. This command is similar to `ssh -V myself@remotehost` (note argument order): they both give the `ssh` client version (as the `-V` argument should):

```
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

How can I specify that I would execute `-V` on the remote host?

⠀

<sup>1</sup> Indeed, that is not really the `-V` command that I would execute. I used the `command="..."` option field into the `authorized_keys` file to get a specific command after login, instead of the shell. Well, I want to give the `-V` parameter to this command. But that is not the question, just a background. :)

Comment: Tried inserting `-- -V`?

Comment: No. And with it, it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-V` is interpreted as a commnad line option.

Insert `--` in order to prevent the command line parameter parser from interpreting following arguments as options (i.e., issue `-- -V`).

Answer (score -1):

You should enclose your command to be executed on the remote server in single quotes and include the full command.

```
ssh myself@remotehost 'ssh -V'
```

Comment: Not exactly. I do not want the remote version of `ssh` (what does your command), but I would like to *execute* `-V` directly. With your single quotes, kind of `ssh myself@remotehost '-V'`, which is the same command as the one given in the question.